# Trying to append csv into another csv AS A ROW but I am getting this AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'writerows'

Tags: python, csv, append, attributeerror

i am trying to append the content in one of my CSV as a ROW to another csv but i am getting this attribute error...I am unsure how to fix it. I think the issue is with writer.writerows(row) but I don't what i should change it to for .writerows(row) to work

This is my below code for appending the first csv to the second csv.

```
with open(csv1', 'r', encoding='utf8') as reader, open(csv2', 'a', encoding='utf8') as writer:
        for row in reader:
            writer.writerows(row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `write()` instead because `writerows()` is belong to `csv.writer`, not normal io. However, if you want to append at the end of the file, you need to make sure that the last row contain new line (i.e., `\n`) already.

```
with open('test1.csv', 'r', encoding='utf8') as reader:
    with open('test2.csv', 'a', encoding='utf8') as writer:
        writer.write("\n") # no need if the last row have new line already
        for line in reader:
            writer.write(line)
```

Or, if you want to use `csv`, you can use `writerows()` as shown in code below:

```
import csv

with open('test1.csv', 'r', encoding='utf8') as reader:
    with open('test2.csv', 'a', encoding='utf8') as writer:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(reader)
        csv_writer = csv.writer(writer)
        csv_writer.writerow([]) # again, no need if the last row have new line already
        csv_writer.writerows(csv_reader)
```